# json_encode does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to convert mysql table data into json but unfortunately it does not return anything.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","truem_apps","censored","truemarlon_apps");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM saechsisch";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My page is just blank what am I missing here?

Comment: Checking your error log, for one.

Comment: even if the query returned no rows, you should **STILL** see at least `[]` from the empty array getting encoded. If you get literally nothing, then something is killing your script. Or your query is outright failing, returning boolean false, meaning that the entire fetch/encode section is simply skipped.

Comment: side note: `$resultArray[]=$row;` cleaner apporach

Comment: @MarcB I've changed `$row = $result->fetch_object()` to `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` and now I get these brackets `[]`. How can I receive the rows?

Comment: That won't work at all since you are using `mysqli` , not `mysql`

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a method in this line: 
`$result->fetch_object();`

`mysqli_query($con, $sql)` doesn't return instance of object. 
use `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` instead.

To encode as JSON object:

```
echo json_encode($row);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me so far that now I get this output: `[false,false]`
My table consists of three colums (id, varchar, varchar). What's the problem here?

Comment: does you table contains data? or it is empty?

Comment: It actually contains entries for testing. All of them have whitespaces I don't know if that's important.

Comment: Your table should contain data to see result

Comment: My table contains data. I figured out the problem. Some of my entries have "ä ö ü" and that's why the output is false. Is there a possibility to get that data?